# Простой jquery-ui dialog с библиотекой knockout

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockoutjs

[оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34300783/simple-jquery-ui-dialog-with-knockout/34302340#34302340)

Я нашел великолепный пример здесь: http://jsfiddle.net/63tGP/39/ (из этого вопроса: knockout bootstrap modal issue) этот пример позволяет пользователю добавлять элементы в иерархию с помощью открытия модального диалога bootstrap. Ключевой момент здесь это использование binding handler библиотеки knockout.
Я бы хотел сделать тоже самое, но только при помощи jquery-ui диалога.
Я модифицировал пример, вот тут: http://jsfiddle.net/63tGP/40/; однако я получил очень странный результат. Может ли кто-нибудь помочь мне исправить мой пример?

Вот пример как я модифицировал binding handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.showModal = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).dialog({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: true, show: false });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value)) {
            $(element).dialog('open');
            $("input", element).focus();
        }
        else {
            $(element).dialog('close');
        }
    }
 };
```

Конечная цель это создать простой компонент, который может быть использован множество раз и который я могу использовать в различных уровнях моей иерархии, для добавления и изменения объектов.

Answer (score 1):

Твой пример правильный, но ты забыл несколько вещей:

1. `JQuery UI` требует `JQuery` для работы.
2. `jquery-ui.js` нужен `jquery-ui.css`
3. ты должен установить порядок вызова библиотек сам. Jsfiddle не сделает это за тебя.

Поэтому корректный порядок будет таким:

1. jquery-ui.css
2. knockout.js
3. jquery.js
4. jquery-ui.js

Я установил скрипты в этом порядке и твой пример заработал:

http://jsfiddle.net/zaj814kz/1/

Но кроме того я рекомендую тебе использовать Require JS загрузчик для того чтобы избежать таких проблем с зависимостями в будущем. Все эти библиотеки: JQuery, JQuery UI, Knockout - поддерживают этот загрузчик (или правильнее AMD подход) по умолчанию. Для примера [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-2.2.1.debug.js) поддерживает это на 14ой строке:

> } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define['amd']) {

Ты не будешь беспокоиться о порядке в котором ты должен вызывать скрипты. Require JS сделает это за тебя. Эта библиотека съэкономит тебе кучу времени, если ты начнешь ее использовать.